# Where can I find open source applications that use lucene.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-source, lucene, lucene.net

I am looking for any open source application that uses lucene.net. I am working on a complicated web application and would like to see how others have implemented lucene.net.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Raven DB](http://ravendb.net/) uses it under the hood.

Comment: Yeah it sure does, RavenDB uses Lucene for all it's indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The [latest release](http://code.google.com/p/subtext/) (2.5) of [SubText](http://subtextproject.com/) uses it.